# Eclipse Rich Client Application Connect to database

Tags: java, eclipse, mongodb, eclipse-rcp, e4

i'm starting a new Eclipse RCP application and it's my first time and i have a problem , i want to display list of my available database(by the way i'm using nosql database(MongoDB)) but my code seems not to work, can anyone help please , can anyone point me to a good tutorial
thanks for your time and help guys.

```
package test2.parts;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.eclipse.e4.ui.di.Focus;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.di.Persist;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.MPart;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ArrayContentProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCursor;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;

public class SamplePart  {


    org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List list ;
    private TableViewer tableViewer;

    @Inject
    private MPart part;

    @PostConstruct
    public void createComposite(Composite parent) {
        parent.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        Text txtInput = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER);
        txtInput.setMessage("Enter text to mark part as dirty");
        txtInput.addModifyListener(e -> part.setDirty(true));
        txtInput.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL));

        list = new org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List(parent, SWT.BORDER);



        tableViewer = new TableViewer(parent);
        tableViewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
        tableViewer.setInput(createInitialDataModel());
        tableViewer.getTable().setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));


    }

    @Focus
    public void setFocus() {
        tableViewer.getTable().setFocus();
    }

    @Persist
    public void save() {
        part.setDirty(false);
    }


    private List<String> createInitialDataModel() {

        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        ArrayList<String> dbs = new ArrayList<String>();
        MongoCursor<String> dbsCursor = mongoClient.listDatabaseNames().iterator();
        while (dbsCursor.hasNext()) {
            list.add(dbsCursor.next());
        }
        return (List<String>) list;

    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pleast post your code as text not images. Images can't be copied to test the code. What does not work? What happens? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: i expect from my code to list the databases names ,

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace shows that the plug-in can't find the MongoClient class.

Eclipse plug-ins can only access code in other plug-ins or in jars included in the plug-in. They can't use jars which are just on the ordinary Java classpath.

So you will need to add the jar containing the MongoClient class in to your plugin and add it to the `Bundle-Classpath` in the MANIFEST.MF. You can do that in the MANIFEST.MF editor in the 'Classpath' section of the 'Runtime' tab.

You also need to include the jar in the build.properties file.